# Sending a delte.php properly to my db

Tags: php, mysql, database, xhtml

I have a function on my that has a delete button to erase comments. I have the button all linked up and ready to go. I just don't know what I should put on the 'delte.php' script I am creating, and what to tell it php wise to send to the db to make the status dead. as well as deleting the comment off of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Need substantially more information before anyone can help you like. What is your DB structure? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Question has been re-asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664721/have-a-delete-button-exaclty-where-i-want-it

Answer (score 2):

Your php script would contain a query to delete the comment

```
mysql_query("delete from comments where id = $id");
```

Send a request using Ajax which won't reload the current webpage. Here is a snippet using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax)

```
function deleteComment(commentId)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: "id="+ commentId,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Comment " + commentId + " deleted" );
   }
 });
}

<a href="#" onclick="deleteComment(1)">Delete Comment 1</a>
```

Comment: If you are going to use jquery, attach the deleteComment() to the links click event using jquery, instead of onclick="". Also, consider validating $id or using PDO with placeholders.  Otherwise, one could delete all of your comments (imagine a commentId of " 1 OR 1=1;--")

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM yourTable WHERE commentId = $id", $yourDbLink);
```

Bobby

Comment: yeah, but how do I do it to where it 1.does not have to go to a different page and deletes it right on the spot (without reloading the page)? I'm assuming a link is not needed

Comment: For better security, use: `$id = intval($_POST['id'])`, or else you could regret it.

Comment: @Ralph The Mouf - you'll need to submit a post request via AJAX to `delete.php`, then capture the response and remove the DOM element corresponding to the deleted item via some JavaScript. This is probably too broad a topic for a single stackoverflow question.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't too much, looks like this answer together with tvor's answer will get you there.

Comment: Alternately, redirect back to the display page after deleting the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the browser to go anywhere you could send HTTP status 204, "No content".

Typically though you'd do a redirect to the same page with a notice saying "Comment deleted." or similar.