# Have a delete button exaclty where I want it

Tags: php, html

and it's linked to a 'confirm comment deleted page. Ideally I would like it to just become erased and have the page reload with it gone, and then send it to my db marked as dead.

Basically, users have a profile which allows other users to make comments.With the help of PHP I would like to be able to have the delete button only show up when a users is looking at their profile.

This is what I have so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `ProfileComments` WHERE `ToUserID` = '".$prof->id."' ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC LIMIT 10";

$request = mysql_query($query,$connection);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {

    $poster = new User($result['FromUserID']);

    echo "<div id='CommentProfile'>";
    echo "<div id='CommentPhotoProfile'>";
    echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/Profile.php?id=".$poster->id."'>";
    echo "<img src='" . $poster->img('mini') . "' border='0'/>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id='ProfileCommentBody' class= 'round_10px'>";
    echo "<div id='CommentNameProfile'>";
    echo "<div class='ProfileCommentTail'>&nbsp;</div>";
    echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/Profile.php?id=".$poster->id."'>";
    echo $poster->first_name. " ". $poster->last_name. " <span style='font-weight:normal'>says...</span>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo stripslashes(nl2br($result['commentProfileBody']));
    echo "<div id='CommentInfoProfile'>";
    echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($result['date']));
    echo " at " . date('g:i A',strtotime($result['time']));
    if ($prof->id == $prof->id)
        echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/DeleteComment.php?id=".$prof->id."'>";
    echo " delete";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

I have asked this question a couple of times today and either gotten vague answers(which is partly my fault because I did not give enough example code which hopefully the above is enough) or I have gotten talked down to,questioned about my ability or told to go hire a developer. haha. So if you are a more experienced developer who wants to share their knowlege with an up and coming developer that would be GREATLY appreciated. Afterall is that not one of the purposes of this site?

If you don't have the time to explain this to me, a link to a great tutorial or resource that can help me find my way would be amazing! thank you.

Comment: You should update your existing question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662337/sending-a-delte-php-properly-to-my-db ?) rather than opening a new one...

Comment: Maybe you've gotten subpar responses because you've asked a subpar question. The code is poorly formatted (yes this matters) and it's not cut down to the bare minimum to explain your problem (which helps readers understand it and demonstrates you've put some effort in rather than doing a code dump saying "fix this").

Comment: Also, in general, SO is about teaching general concepts, not writing specific code for you. As such, while there's nothing _wrong_ with asking, don't be surprised if the answers are less than helpful at times if you're basically asking people to do it for you. Anyway - a note of clarification - do you want to know what goes in `DeleteComment.php`, or do you want to know what's broken in the above code, or what?

Comment: I hear ya, but I think I am being misunderstood, I am not by any means asking people to 'do it for me' I just have never done this before and am looking for resources on how to do it. I mean how are you supposed to learn? I have to have some sort of reference. Does that make sense? so yes...I do want to know what is broken, and I am if what goes in a DeleteComment.php contains script that deletes the comment off of my page and marks it dead in my db than yes, or at least a helpful resource I could look at. Thank you.

Comment: and as far as the sub par question. I understand my previous questions were not well asked, so I am trying to be as detailed as possible to give a helpful example

Comment: @Ralph, one of the problems here is not detail, but rather it's unclear exactly what you're asking. You've stated what you want to do, given a bit of code you've written, but nowhere did you put _what you want us to answer_. When that happens, we'll have to guess what you meant - and we might not guess correctly :) It's helpful to always write a single-sentence question in the question's title, and also at the very end of the question body, to help focus your post. This should help you get better responses in the future! :)

Comment: @bdonlan if you are still interested in helping, my question is am I on the right track to making my delete button only show up on the users profile?

and where can I find out how to truely delete this comment both off of my site and out of my db?

Comment: @Ralph, it's hard to say, all you have there is a button. You're going to need a button, sure, but the real work will be over in `DeleteComment.php`. Why don't you try writing it and see how it goes? (also see my answer for an important note - the argument you're passing to `DeleteComment.php` is probably not what you mean to pass in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
if ($prof->id == $prof->id)
```

to

```
if ($poster->id == $prof->id)
```

so that the delete link only shows up when the profile belongs to the poster.

Comment: i put this at first too, but i think he wanted it only when the logged in user was looking at his own profile. although it wouldn't surprise me if it was worded incorrectly in the question.

Comment: Man, people are harsh on here.

Comment: Sorry if I said something to offend you somewhere - I didn't mean to be harsh above; I'm just trying to give advice on how to get better answers to your future questions, since you seemed to be having bad luck at it. I would suggest reading ESR's "How to ask smart questions" @ http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - he comes off a bit harsh too, but he makes a lot of good points on how to communicate what you want to know effectively, and how to get good responses.

Comment: thanks bdonlan, your not harsh, I was actually referring to a couple of others on here. You've been a great help though. Thank you!

Comment: what you suggest would put the delete button on all of the profile owner's comments even if the profile owner isn't the one looking at the profile. the asker used it as the correct answer, but i don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem here? It looks like you've got the 'delete' link set up properly, now all you need to do is create that `DeleteComment` page. In it, you would do something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // make sure to sanitize this variable
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ProfileComments WHERE id=$id");
header('location:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // redirect to last page
```

Others might also recommend that you use `POST` rather than `GET` for reasons I don't feel like getting into here (spiders might "click" it). And you'll probably want to make sure users are logged in or something like that too. And `REQUEST_URI` isn't reliable either supposedly, because it depends on the client's browser sending that information to you. You can get around this by saving the last URL in a session or something like that.

Comment: i think the problem is the delete link is showing up for everybody, because his if statement compares the same variable to itself.

Comment: ah... i got distracted by all the other nonsense in his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($prof->id == $prof->id)
    echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/DeleteComment.php?id=".$prof->id."'>";
```

this should always result to true.

looks like you need

```
if ($logged_in_user->id == $prof->id)
    echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/DeleteComment.php?id=".$prof->id."'>";
```

i should also note that the id you're passing to your delete link is the id of the profile instead of the comment itself. you probably don't want to delete a whole profile here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($prof->id == $prof->id)
```

This will always be true. Did you mean:

```
if ($prof->id == $poster->id)
```

I'm assuming `$prof` is the profile of the logged-in user. If this isn't the case, you'll need to use something else here! (Please indicate what variables are if it's not clear in code samples, it'll help us help you)

Be sure to recheck this in `DeleteComment.php` - just because there's no button doesn't mean an enterprising hacker won't make one for themselves!

Also,

```
echo "<a href='http://www.blahblah.org/DeleteComment.php?id=".$prof->id."'>";
```

If I understand your variables correctly, `$prof` is the logged-in user profile; not the comment. So this has no way of specifying what comment needs to be deleted; only the currently logged-in user. You may want to pass in the comment's ID instead - since you didn't post your schema, I can't give specific code here though.